# ambiguous for type lookup in this context when -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1 is active

Tags: ios, core-data

The code below runs perfectly fine when I have the above parameter turned off in my Scheme.  When it is turned on I get a 'Group' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context crash error. on the line "let currentGroup = context.object(with: groupID) as? Group"

I've checked my project and there is no duplicate reference to Group NSManagedObject.

```
let context = CoreDataStack.shared.newPrivateContext()
    if reset {
        AppDefault.current_ListGroup = nil
    }
    if let groupID = AppDefault.current_ListGroup,
         let currentGroup = context.object(with: groupID) as? Group {
        return currentGroup.objectID
    } else {
```

Can someone help me figure out why it works with the .ConcurrencyDebug 1 off but crashes when it is on?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When concurrency debugging is on, the app will crash any time you break the concurrency rules. Breaking the rules on its own doesn't always crash the app-- but with debugging enabled, you're saying that you want to crash as soon as you break the rules, even if the app would work normally without debugging. This is a good thing, because breaking the rules will probably make the app crash eventually even if it doesn't happen right now.

How you're breaking the rules here is:

- You're creating a new private queue context with `newPrivateContext`.
- You're using that context without calling `perform` or `performAndWait`.

With a private queue context, you **must** use one of those functions whenever you use the context. Really the only time you don't have to use one of those is if you're using main queue concurrency **and** you know that your code is running on the main queue. You can sometimes get away with not doing that, if everything is just right, but concurrency debugging will stop you immediately. That's what you're seeing.

Comment: I am creating the background context using the call to the persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext() which uses the ConcurrencyType privateQueueConcurrencyType.  So, I was breaking the rules and your answer has put me on the right path. Thank you.  I will update everywhere I use the .newBackgroundContext()